# sky label is not translated

Tags: magento, localization, magento2

I want to translate and change the SKU label, I did it in the admin panel but it didn't work.
I have version 2.1.4
Here is my admin : 
[image]

I cleared cache but didn't work:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's in **Properties** tab: **Default label**